# Does a two layer CRUD python appengine demo exist?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, authentication, crud

I have developed a handful of appengine apps which I finally have realized are examples of CRUD on top of CRUD. That is, I, the adminstrator, offer my app to users so they can either use the app (say a note taker app) themselves or can invite other acquaintances, typically non-users, to exercise the ultimate app (for example, [ParticiPoll, a participative questionnaire](http://ParticiPoll.appspot.com) which uses the google appengine datastore and no SQL). My only and quite young grandson has asked me to produce a screencast video showing how such 2 layer CRUD's can be created, so that he can develop such apps, but I don't even have a coded demo to start from.

I have studied and exercised [the single layer note taking CRUD demo](https://github.com/fRuiApps/cpfthw/tree/master/webapp2) and have been impressed with it's simplicity and clarity. I would like to build another CRUD layer on top of that demo, in much the same format, with the ability to authenticate users and give them ability to control the extent of security required of the ultimate users (for example captcha, or not, and when), their "acquaintances."

I would like to know if other demos already exist. I have found alternatives such as  [django administrator's site](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/) which is too complex and too tied to django, imo. (Also, Django has gotten rather monolithic to me, too.) So that is my main question: does such a simple demo already exist and if so, where?

I am also struggling with how open_id is coded on appengine and may not include this very desirable feature in such a demo. Is that a good decision?

Brian in Atlanta

Comment: so what you basically want is ACL ? Gopal in India.

Comment: @iamgopal The only reference to ACL I could find was [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Communication_Language). Could you clarify, please?

Comment: @zenwords http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list

Comment: @iamgopal Oh. I see. No. That is not what I am talking about. I am looking for a python code demo that builds a second CRUD layer on top of the one [above](https://github.com/fRuiApps/cpfthw/tree/master/webapp2) : a CRUD layer that manages the users who independently employ the note-taking facility in the CRUD example.