# Google App Engine Python WebApp sequence

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi

```
import webapp2
from views import MainPageNote, CreateNote, DeleteNote, EditNote, \
                    MainPage, CreateOwner, DeleteOwner, EditOwner

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage), 
        ('/createowner', CreateOwner), 
        ('/editowner', EditOwner),
        ('/deleteowner', DeleteOwner)
        ('/note', MainPageNote), 
        ('/create', CreateNote), 
        ('/edit/([\d]+)', EditNote),
        ('/delete/([\d]+)', DeleteNote)
        ],
        debug=True)
```

I don't know how to ask this question more efficiently because I don't know the terminology.
Where can I learn about the importance of the sequence of lines in the web app list and actually designing the list? Most of the '/...owner' type items will include "?ID=..." trailers, so I am not even sure this system will work. For context, I am working on developing [the demo app described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657352/does-a-two-layer-crud-python-appengine-demo-exist)

I assume that all of the lefthand items in the list are "regular expressions", but I don't  the rules for ordering the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [webapp2 URL routing](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the reference I need. But I don't understand whether, for example, `('/createowner', CreateOwner), ` or `('/create', CreateNote),` should come first. It seems to me that `('/createowner', CreateOwner), ` must be first.  And similarly with the sequence `editowner` and `edit`, `edit owner` must be first. Right?

Comment: But if that's correct, then how can `('/', MainPage), ` be first without matching all of the ones after it? Does `('/', MainPage), ` have to be last? I am confused.

Comment: It will do a literal compare so '/createowner' != '/create' hence it doesn't matter who comes first.

Comment: You will have a problem if you have an handler at '/admin/console' and an handler at '/admin/.*' if you won't put the former first it will never be called.