# 404 error constructing link from parameter from "def get(self, notebook_id):"

Tags: html, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am getting the dreaded 404 html error message with this url

```
http://localhost:8088/editnotebook/Roger
```

The link is produced with this href.

```
{% for page in pages %}
<li><a href="/editnotebook/{{ page }}">  {{ page }} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The python code is as follows.

```
def get(self, notebook_id):
    iden = notebook_id
    notebook = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Notebooks', iden))
    self.render_template('editnotebook.html', {'notebook': notebook})
```

The model is as follows.

```
from models import Notes, Notebooks

class Notebooks(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty()
    moreinfo = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    deleteRequested = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

Is that enough information to tell why I am getting the 404 error and maybe fix it?

This question is related to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657352/does-a-two-layer-crud-python-appengine-demo-exist).

Comment: `app.yaml` and `routes.py` will probably be more relevant here.

Comment: Yes, the routes.py was exactly the problem. I had not added to the links `([\w]+)`. Thanks very much.  `('/editnotebook/([\w]+)', EditNotebook),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hyperslug really answered this by noticing that I had not posted my routes.py code. 
In the routes.py you have to add the regex ([\w]+) to accommodate the link parameter.